# Cloud Run endpoint protected with ESP/Endpoints taking over 500ms?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-run

I deployed a Cloud Run service and for testing purpose, expose a simple service that responds with a static JSON {"result": "ok"}

I removed "all users" from the role binding, only allowing access to ESP. When I call ESP, the latency is above 500ms and often over 1500ms. This happens even after repeated calls, so I know it isn't a container startup issue.

In the YAML file I used for configuring ESP, the target is the https endpoint I receive from Cloud Run. I suspect that the authorization and double TLS termination (on ESP and on the Cloud Run endpoint) have something to do with the apparent slowness, but I'd appreciate some guidance from Google on way to speed up the response. As-is, the performance is not really acceptable.

Comment: What ESP are you using?

Comment: gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime-serverless:1.30.0

Comment: And you run it cloud run also? In the same region?

Comment: Yes, I run ESP on cloud run in us-central1

Comment: BTW, it may not make much different in your performance. could you use ESP image with tag "1" instead of "1.30.0"?   "1" will always point to the latest image.

Comment: You can use cloud console to check stack driver traces for your requests.  It will show the latency spend in ESP.

Comment: It seems the issue is not with ESP. I am seeing >400ms. response times calling from Ventura County, CA into us-central1. No authentication, calling the service directly. See this code for the simple service: https://github.com/dorongrinstein/cloudrun-dummy-service

And see this code for the test:
https://github.com/dorongrinstein/cloudrun-test

I call the exposed endpoint 50 times, and see a >400ms. for every call.
I reported this to Google but I have not received a response.

Comment: BTW: When I use gcpping.com I see a median latency of 70ms. So it isn't my internet connection.